# CMake Cross Platform Compile: file cannot create directory: /data. Maybe need administrative privileges

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, cpack

I am trying to compile, depending on the detected system, a `tar.gz` file, or a `.deb` file.

Using the below code, I am able to successfully create a `.deb` file when the detected system is Linux, however when compiling for QNX which recquires a `.tar.gz' file, I receive the error:

```
file cannot create directory: /data.  Maybe need administrative
  privileges.
```

This command for the system should not and cannot be run as `sudo`, and even when attempting running the make command as `sudo make install` I receive errors relating to the compile environment (configured for QNX).

My CMakeList.txt code:

```cmake
set(CPACK_ARCHIVE_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
if( "${CMAKE_CXX_PLATFORM_ID}" MATCHES QNX )
    message( STATUS "QNX found" )
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR "STGZ")
else()
    message( STATUS "defaulting to Linux" )
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB") 
endif()

install(
        TARGETS         binary 
        DESTINATION     "/data/"
        )  

include(CPack)
```

Comment: My guess is the leader slash in your `install` command is making cmake treat it as an absolute directory.  What happens if you just use `data` instead of `/data/`?

Comment: @StephenNewell This was it thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen Newell [mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590627/cmake-cross-platform-compile-file-cannot-create-directory-data-maybe-need-ad/61605297#comment108952604_61590627):

> My guess is the leader slash in your `install` command is making cmake treat it as an absolute directory.  What happens if you just use `data` instead of `/data/`?

Using `data` instead of `/data/` solved the problem.