# cmake install error: file cannot create directory. Maybe need administrative priviliges (using Dockerfile)

Tags: docker, opencv, cmake, dockerfile

#### Problem

I'm trying to install OpenCV using a Dockerfile, but I keep running into one error...
It seems that the `sudo make install` step in the Dockerfile doesn't have the right privileges, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it.

#### Error

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:98 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4.  Maybe need
  administrative privileges.
```

#### Things I tried to solve it

- Install `sudo` package and do `sudo make install` instead of `make install`
- Other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61605297/9437734

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc:latest

ARG RUNTIME_DEPS='sudo libpng libjpeg-turbo libwebp tiff jasper openexr openblas zlib'
ARG BUILD_DEPS='wget unzip cmake build-base python3 py3-pip linux-headers libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libwebp-dev tiff-dev openexr-dev jasper-dev openblas-dev zlib-dev'
ARG LIB_PREFIX='/usr/local'
ARG VERSION=4.5.5

ENV OPENCV_VERSION=${VERSION} \
    LIB_PREFIX=${LIB_PREFIX}

RUN echo "OpenCV: ${OPENCV_VERSION}" \
    && echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && rm -rf /usr/local/lib && ln -s /usr/local/lib64 /usr/local/lib \
    && apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add -u --no-cache $RUNTIME_DEPS \
    && apk add -u --no-cache --virtual .build-dependencies $BUILD_DEPS \
    && wget -q https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv.zip \
    && wget -q https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv_contrib.zip \
    && mkdir /opencv \
    && mv opencv.zip opencv_contrib.zip /opencv \
    && cd /opencv \
    && unzip -qq opencv.zip \
    && mv opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION} opencv \
    && unzip -qq opencv_contrib.zip \
    && mv opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION} opencv_contrib \
    && mkdir opencv/build \
    && cd opencv/build \
    && opencv_cmake_flags="-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_JAVA=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_aruco=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_bgsegm=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_bioinspired=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_ccalib=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_datasets=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_dnn_objdetect=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_dpm=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_fuzzy=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_hfs=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_java_bindings_generator=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_js=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_img_hash=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_line_descriptor=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_optflow=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_phase_unwrapping=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_reg=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_rgbd=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_saliency=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_shape=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_stereo=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_structured_light=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_superres=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_surface_matching=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_ts=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_xobjdetect=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_xphoto=OFF \
    -D WITH_VTK=OFF \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$LIB_PREFIX \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules" \
    && cmake $opencv_cmake_flags .. \
    && make -j $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && cd /opencv/opencv/build \
    && sudo make install \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf /opencv \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig \
    && apk del .build-dependencies \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /usr/share/man /usr/local/share/man /tmp/*
```

#### My question

How to correctly install OpenCV in Docker? Other Dockerfile setups are always welcome!

#### Edit

Right before the `sudo make install`, inside the Dockerfile, I tried to create the folder manually by executing `mkdir /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4`.

The result:

```
mkdir: can't create directory '/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4': No such file or directory
```

I'm now going to replace `mkdir /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4` with the following command: `mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4`

Comment: What `USER` are you?  (You should not normally need `sudo` in a Dockerfile, since you can freely switch `USER` as often as you need to.)

Comment: @DavidMaze how do I check what `USER` I am? I didn't change any settings, this is the complete Dockerfile btw.

Comment: https://github.com/Borda/docker_python-opencv-ffmpeg/blob/master/cpu/Dockerfile